# How can I get a reasonable plaster finish in an awkward recess?

Tags: drywall, plaster

I am plastering my basement, having drywalled it. It's mostly done, but there is an awkward recess around the gas meter that I still need to do:

[image: Gas meter]

Would just leave the plasterboard exposed and paint it, but there is scrim tape at the edges, and also several joins / screw heads to cover.

[image: Gas meter close up]

It doesn't need to perfect, as it'll be boxed in, in a cupboard, but I want to get a reasonable finish that I can paint. I suspect trying to plaster it will be a nightmare, as I'll be unable to get a trowel behind the meter (may leave it looking worse than before). How else can I make a paintable finish? Wondered about joint compound and then sanding it.

Anyone got any better ideas?!

Comment: If it will be hidden in a cupboard, why not just leave it as is? You really didn't even need to drywall it, but since it's there now, just leave and hide it in the cupboard.

Comment: Alternatively:  dab a bit of joint compound over the screw heads and joints, tool it roughly flat (a damp finger may be as good a tool as any for dealing with tight corners), and don't worry about it. As @aphoria noted, you've already gone above and beyond common practice, and inside a closet it isn't exactly going to get close inspection with a raking light...

Comment: Agree @aphoria - I should get a life ;-) Joint compound seems like a plan though.

Comment: Unless you want to bother to have the gas shut off and the meter pulled so you can gild the plaster lily in the closet, the answer provided seems best. If you do go there, be sure to paint a tiny copy of the mona lisa or scream (or some other instantly recognizable painting) behind it for the next person that pulls the meter to find.

Comment: Haha! Outstanding. Will do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use joint compound, and smooth it in with a putty knife as smoothly as possible.  Then, when it's dry, use a damp sponge to smooth it over to a paintably smooth surface.